Ubuntu Server 24.04 systemd-networkd-wait-online.service Warning in journald
I just installed a new Ubuntu 24.04 and found these warnings in my log file.
Althogh I changed the the rights the warning came back after reboot.
keyhub systemd[1]: Configuration file /run/systemd/system/systemd-networkd-wait-online.service.d/10-netplan.conf is marked world-inaccessible. This has no effect as configuration data is accessible via APIs without restrictions. Proceeding anyway.
keyhub systemd[1]: Configuration file /run/systemd/system/netplan-ovs-cleanup.service is marked world-inaccessible. This has no effect as configuration data is accessible via APIs without restrictions. Proceeding anyway.

How can I fix this?

These messages are just informational and can be ignored. As the message says, "This has no effect as configuration data is accessible via APIs without restrictions."

I dont want these entries in my log.
